# How to sync node_modules directory from Docker container to Host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node-modules, docker-volume

I use Ubuntu 22.04 as a host machine and Docker 20.10.17 for the container environment.

Problem is that when I install the node packages inside the container, then I do not see these packages in the host machine in the node_modules folder, it's empty, so the IDE (Visual Studio Code) just gives errors in every TypeScript file cause of the missing node packages.

However, in the container, I can see, the node pcakges are installed and there under the node_modules folder, so the application is up and live. So it works there, just locally, on my host machine is not available.

I added the `node_modules` as a volume in the `docker-compose.yml`, but that trick does not work as I have seen this in other posts.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    stdin_open: true
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

# Fix Permissions for Packages
# RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Fix Cache Permissions for node_modules
RUN chown -R node /app

USER node

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

The project structure looks like this on the host machine:

```
/
- node_modules/
- public/
- src/
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: If you're trying to run the program directly on the host, and you have Node there too, I'm not clear why Docker needs to be forced into your development flow.  I'd run `npm install` normally on the host (and I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` block from your Compose file).

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks, yes, this could work, but in the past 1 years ago I could you only the docker images to handle the full development flow.

Comment: The normal workflow I use is to use standard host development tools for day-to-day development, and only bring Docker into the system for (a) dependencies like databases or caches, (b) local integration testing, and (c) final deployment.  Other workflows are possible, but especially for a routine Node application, it's not obvious to me what the benefits of hiding Node inside Docker are over using it directly.